# Short link of a TechCrunch article

Tags: url-shortening

Where can I retrieve the short link on a TechCrunch article?

E.g. the article http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/03/citusdb-releases-an-open-source-postgresql-tool-that-promises-better-database-performance/ has http://tcrn.ch/1dR1Q0w as short link. Where can I find the shortlink on the article page?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of share links at the bottom of the article. If you click the one for Twitter, it'll bring you to a pre-filled tweet form, which includes the shortened URL.

Comment: The question seems to be about _TechChrunch_'s URL shortener, not Twitter's.

Comment: @Vidar: The answer was referring to the share links found at the bottom of all TechCrunch articles. I've attempted to make the answer more clear.

Comment: These share links are now at the top (and sometimes *also* bottom) of the article on large screens and fixed to the bottom on small screens